# Values retrieval from Edit Text and calculate the total

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity, android-edittext, android-button

I'm trying to get the values from a Edit text and trying to calcluate and put it in a textview. but im getting a error while converting to string from double.

This is my edit text code:

```
<EditText
     android:id="@+id/c"
     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:ems="10"
     android:gravity="center"
     android:inputType="number" >
    <requestFocus />
</EditText>
<EditText
            android:id="@+id/b"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:ems="10"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:inputType="number" >

            <requestFocus />
        </EditText>
<EditText
    android:id="@+id/a"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:ems="10"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:inputType="number" >
    <requestFocus />
</EditText>
```

Here is my Activity class :

```
a= (EditText) findViewById(R.id.a);
b= (EditText) findViewById(R.id.b);
c= (EditText) findViewById(R.id.c);
String aa= a.getText().toString();
String bb= b.getText().toString();
String cc= c.getText().toString();
Double total= (Double.valueOf(aa)*Double.valueOf(bb)) + (Double.valueOf(aa)*Double.valueOf(cc)) ;
totalbill = Double.toString(total);
Button submitbutn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.submitbutton);
submitbutn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {       
            d.setText(totalbill);
        }
    });
}
```

The error log is :

```
10-08 07:27:58.115: E/AndroidRuntime(1909): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.vat.calculator/com.vat.calculator.Home}: java.lang.NumberFormatException: Invalid double: ""
10-08 07:27:58.115: E/AndroidRuntime(1909):     at java.lang.Double.parseDouble(Double.java:295)
10-08 07:27:58.115: E/AndroidRuntime(1909):     at java.lang.Double.valueOf(Double.java:332)
10-08 07:27:58.115: E/AndroidRuntime(1909):     at java.lang.StringToReal.invalidReal(StringToReal.java:63)
10-08 07:27:58.115: E/AndroidRuntime(1909):     at java.lang.StringToReal.parseDouble(StringToReal.java:248)
```

Comment: use `Double.parseDouble("your string value")`;

Comment: If you will not enter any number in EditText and click submit button then blank space is converting to number thats why you are getting [NumberFormatException](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/NumberFormatException.html), Check my answer how to validate before parsing String to Double.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this code....

```
    a= (EditText) findViewById(R.id.a);
    b= (EditText) findViewById(R.id.b);
    c= (EditText) findViewById(R.id.c);

    Button submitbutn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.submitbutton);
    submitbutn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View v) {
            String aa= a.getText().toString();
            String bb= b.getText().toString();
            String cc= c.getText().toString();

            double aDouble = aa.length() > 0 ? Double.valueOf(aa) : 0;
            double bDouble = bb.length() > 0 ? Double.valueOf(bb) : 0;
            double cDouble = cc.length() > 0 ? Double.valueOf(cc) : 0;

            Double total= (aDouble * bDouble) + (aDouble * cDouble) ;
            totalbill = Double.toString(total);

            d.setText(totalbill);
        }
    });
```

Comment: The mistake i did was that i was calling the Edittext in oncreate method which is crap. thanks @vishesh chandra to mark me out. :)

Answer (score 0):

Before Double.parse please check wether the String is not empty.

```
if(aa != null && aa.length() > 0){
   Double.parse(aa);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Change this line

```
totalbill = Double.toString(total);
```

to

```
totalbill = total.toString();
```

comment me about result

Answer (score 0):

You can try with [parseDouble()](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/Double.html#parseDouble%28java.lang.String%29);

```
Double total= (Double.parseDouble(aa)*Double.parseDouble(bb))...
```

And check `aa!=null` `bb!=null` and `cc!=null` and not empty

Answer (score 0):

Try below code:

```
 if(aa != null && aa.length() > 0 && bb ! = null && bb.length>0 && cc!=null && cc.length>0){
        Double total= ((Double.parseDouble(aa))*(Double.parseDouble(bb)) + ((Double.parseDouble(aa))*(Double.parseDouble(cc)) ;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Your application may be throwing a **null pointer exception**. so to avoid this try this:

```
if(aa != null && aa.length() > 0 && bb ! = null && bb.length>0 && cc!=null && cc.length>0){
        Double total= ((Double.parseDouble(aa))*(Double.parseDouble(bb)) + ((Double.parseDouble(aa))*(Double.parseDouble(cc)) ;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Trim the Strings and parse to double and check the length of the string is not empty

```
if(aa != null && aa.trim().length() > 0){
  Double.valueOf(aa.trim())
}
```